# Solace nodejs api to retrieve message from message spool Queue

Tags: node.js, message-queue, solace

While doing connect through the Nodejs api to the Solace message persistence queue, we encounter error:

> {"message":"Consumer is not supported by router for this client","name":"OperationError","subcode":3,"reason":null}

on using the Solace Node.js API sample to connected to the Persistence Message Queue with the Web Message URI using soladmin.

```
 consumer.connect = function (argv) {
        if (consumer.session !== null) {
            consumer.log('Already connected and ready to consume messages.');
            return;
        }
        // extract params
        //if (argv.length < (2 + 3)) { // expecting 3 real arguments
        if (argv.length < 4) {
            consumer.log('Cannot connect: expecting all arguments' +
                '[<protocol://host[:port]>, <client-username>, <message-vpn>, <client-password>].\n' +
                'Available protocols are ws://, wss://, http://, https://');
            process.exit();
        }
        var hosturl = argv[0] //argv.slice(2)[0];
        consumer.log('Connecting to Solace message router using url: ' + hosturl);
        //var usernamevpn = argv.slice(3)[0];
        var username = argv[1]//usernamevpn.split('@')[0];
        consumer.log('Client username: ' + username);
        var vpn = argv[2]//usernamevpn.split('@')[1];
        consumer.log('Solace message router VPN name: ' + vpn);
        var pass = argv[3]//argv.slice(4)[0];
        // create session
        try {
            consumer.session = solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
                // solace.SessionProperties
                url: hosturl,
                vpnName: vpn,
                userName: username,
                password: pass,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            consumer.log(error.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message `"Consumer is not supported by router for this client"` indicates that the issue is on the remote end.

Check if the client-profile allows the client to receive guaranteed messages. Otherwise, there may be a problem with the message spool that prevents the message broker from providing guaranteed messaging service.

The code snippet in the question is for initiating a connection only, and has nothing to do with connecting to the queue. The operation that failed should be

```
consumer.messageConsumer.connect();
```